# Selenium paste text into textarea

Tags: c#, .net, selenium

Using Selenium, I'd like to edit the contents of a `textarea`. Calling `textarea.SendKeys("My text")` works, but it types it in letter by letter which is obviously quite slow for longer strings.

One workaround I found (http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=2876) suggests that I copy the string to a clipboard and paste it into the `textarea`. The `Keys` reference they give is ambiguous between `OpenQA.Selenium.Keys` and `System.Windows.Forms.Keys`, so I tried both of them. Here's my code to do that:

```
Clipboard.SetDataObject("My  text");
textarea.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Control + "v");
```

This freezes the application. If I use `System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Control` instead, it types in controlv, which obviously is not what I want.

Does anyone have any idea as to what the problem might be?

Answer (score 3):

I am able to use the same SendKeys when setting the clipboard to text:

```
Clipboard.SetText(trgt);
myTextArea.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Control + "v");
```

so perhaps the SetDataObject is an issue

Answer (score 1):

Hope this CopyPaste method helps:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;
     public void CopyPaste(string copy)
    {
        Clipboard.SetText(copy);
        new Actions(driver).SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.LeftShift + OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Insert).Perform();
//because it switch to uppercase we do one more click
        new Actions(driver).SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.LeftShift).Perform();
    }

texarea.Click;
// if driver refuse to click textarea you can force it with:
//((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='MyTextareaId']")));
// not proven, but I think textarea.SendKeys(""); Will click inside the textarea


//Call the method
CopyPaste("Text Appear In the Textarea");
```