# How can selenium enter multiple chars at once?

Tags: browser, selenium, selenium-webdriver

My question concerns a text input box that evaluates the input after each char is entered.

In selenium,

```
element.sendKeys(string);
```

sends each char in the string as an individual key press (which makes sense). But in real life i can push a couple keys quick enough that the input box takes in 2+ chars at once.

How can I simulate this with selenium?

Do i need to do a 'copy/paste' or is there another way?

Comment: I just wrote answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50292371/4334702 CopyPaste method.

Answer (score 2):

If you use Java then you can try to use "Paste" way

```
setClipboardContents(longText);
textarea.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "v");
```

If C# you can try to use:

```
Clipboard.SetText(longText);
textarea.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "v");
```